# REST API: nodejs vs python

Tags: node.js

I want to make Restful API for current PHP application with mongodb backend database.

NodeJS (express) vs Python (web.py), which is better for performance?

Comment: why don't you code it in php if you are using it already?

Comment: Can not find a out box solution to export Restful API in PHP.

Comment: Express has the advantage of asynchronous I/O.  For database I/O it's better for performance.

Comment: I think you can use nodejs because it has more basic advantages like javascript object and json are easily convertible. Sometimes no need to parse result of rest api separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found some [speed test article](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/javascript/83865/). It's written in Russian so you may not able to read this. But you can look at the code for examples.

Here simple test results and short translation of explanation:

**Python, Tornado**

```
ab -n 10 -c 10 http://127.0.0.1:8888/
Time taken for tests:   20.078 seconds
```

**Node.js**

```
ab -n 10 -c 10 http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Time taken for tests:   2.007 seconds
```

There is no description of testing computer but it's not so matter.

The reason why Node.js is faster is that it uses nonblocking event loop while Python's time.sleep is blocking.

#### Update 2021

Since Python has received [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html), the benchmarks from the article aren't complete without tests of asyncio.

Comment: This result doesn't seem to be realistic. Look at http://mrjoes.github.com/2011/12/15/sockjs-bench.html